# How can I change a cookie value from a WebMethod?

Tags: cookies, asp.net

```
  [WebMethod]
  public static void SetTheme(string theme)
  {
   Guid studentIdentifier = SessionData.LoggedInUser.Identifier;
   Student student = (Student)ItemFactory.GetItem(studentIdentifier);
   student.Theme = theme;
  }
```

And I want to change the cookie that is also named "theme", at the end of this WebMethod. How can I accomplish that? The cookie has to be set here, not through JavaScript. That is a requirement. Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access the HttpContext in your webMethod, and from there, acess the response object.

```
var response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
```

The HttpResponse object allows you to access the cookies sent to the browser with the response:

```
if(response.Cookies["theme"]!=null)
  response.Cookies["theme"].Value = myValue;
```

the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.cookies.aspx) makes a good job explaining it. You can access the request cookies too, using HttpContext.Current.Request

Comment: You are right, I had to use:
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["theme"].Value = theme;
Thank you.