# using WebMethod to read cookie but no Request.Cookies collection

Tags: asp.net, cookies, webmethod

I am trying to read cookie without post back. I used WebMethod to save the cookie, but cannot find way to retrieve it. For some reason, I cannot find Request.Cookies collection so that I can retrieve the value of it. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I change a cookie value from a WebMethod?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041031/how-can-i-change-a-cookie-value-from-a-webmethod)

Comment: I figured it out. The reason why I could not use Request in my WebMethod was that the method was static.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use  this in your web method

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies
```